# Need the sshd server be run in root privilege for a password-less login?

Tags: ssh, permissions, security, sshd

### I mean:

if the sshd is't being run in root account, then how can it let the remote ssh client run shell or other command in root account ?

if sshd call the login command, then the user could login as the root. becuase the user supplied the root passowrd, and the UNIX knows it.

BUT sshd also has a passowrd-less function. That is it stores the public key of the ssh client. In this situation, the ssh client don't type in a password for the login command.  how the UNIX system let the ssh client run shell as ROOT user ?  if the sshd is not a root account.

### Original:

My question is sshd can be used to login server without a password.

so, need it to be run in root privilege ?

If not, how does the server allow the client to run in root account ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to make `sshd` server ask for a password when trying to login?

Comment: If user supply a password then, sshd just use this password to open a shell, redirect the io to remote. how can the sshd server do this without a password and root privilege?

Comment: This question would benefit from proofreading by someone with a better command of English. I don't understand what you mean either.

Comment: No. If you run `sshd` without root privileges and use public key authentication, than you can log in only as the user running the `sshd`. For other users you need the password to get the shell if I am right.

Answer (score 1):

It was asked before on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/344295/is-it-possible-to-run-sshd-as-a-normal-user). Quoting with few modification and notes:

> Start the process with `/usr/sbin/sshd -f ~/.ssh/sshd_config` where `~/.ssh/sshd_config` is a new file you created. Among other options (such as a different host key, different port, etc) you need to add the line `UsePrivilegeSeparation no`. This will prevent the `sshd` process from trying to do any `setuid` or `setgid` calls and allow it to continue running as your user and accept connections as your user.

Also don't forget to use unprivileged port (>1024).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need is `ssh-keygen`, which remembers your "device signature". So even you changed your password, it still works as long as you `ssh` from the same device.

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and) is a detailed tutorial how to set it up.

Does it need to be run in root privilege?

- No, you only need root privilege on the host-server when you set it up, in order to edit some file under the home directory of `root`. Once it is set up, you can do it without entering the root password anymore.